# jsTestDriver: org.jvyaml.ParserException when running tests

Tags: javascript, exception, js-test-driver, sinon

I try to run javascript tests with jsTestDriver. When I start the tests, an exception occured.

[image: exception description]

The problem does not occur when the .conf file of jsTestDriver contains only one filepath in args, e.g.:

```
plugin:
 - name: "coverage"
   jar: "plugins/coverage-1.3.4.b.jar"
   module: "com.google.jstestdriver.coverage.CoverageModule"
   args: "/examplepath/data/jsdevelopment/src/webhome/bp2011/js/external/jquery.js"

timeout: 60
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I split the paths in args with quotes like

```
args: "/examplepath/data/jsdevelopment/src/webhome/bp2011/js/external/jquery.js", "/examplepath2/data/jsdevelopment/src/webhome/bp2011/js/external/jquery.js"
```

The solution is:

```
args: "/examplepath/data/jsdevelopment/src/webhome/bp2011/js/external/jquery.js,/examplepath2/data/jsdevelopment/src/webhome/bp2011/js/external/jquery.js"
```